# How would one describe the relationship of next-to-adjacent?

Tags: synonyms

In other words, say there are three or more objects, how would you describe the relationship between object one and object three?

For context clarity, I am referring to the lateral positioning relationship of teeth. I am discussing the relationship between tooth number 7 and tooth number 9. Number 8 in this situation would be the adjacent tooth. What would number 9 be?

Answer (score 2):

I have found the terminology '**second adjacent**' used in the way you are seeking.

It is used in a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacent_channel) discussing broadcasting channels.

[Radio World](https://www.radioworld.com/misc-1/thirdadjacent-protection-review) also uses the terms 'second adjacent' and 'third adjacent' in respect of the same background - that of radio channels, meaning the next to adjacent and the next one after that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you don't just refer to tooth number 9 (since it has a designation anyway), I would use **on the other side**.

As in:

> I know this incisor is healthy, but what about the premolar *on the other side* of the canine?

---

Or, in other words, tooth 8 is *between* teeth 7 and 9, and teeth 7 and 9 are on *either side* of tooth 8—or they *surround* it.

Answer (score 0):

The word you are looking for is [neighboring](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/neighboring).